# Link to my wordpress blog in main menu is "dead"?

Tags: wordpress, menu, hyperlink

I 've created a website www.milan-kresojevic.com.Everything is fine and now installed wordpress blog plugin to my server and started building a blog to.You can notice that when you come to the main menu on this website,and right click on the "Blog" button,you can open it in new window so the link seems to be working.BUT...

When you left-click on in as every normal link- it doesn't work :/

This is a bit confusing,and I've tried changing it in a zillion ways,and it is still the same.

Right-click "open in a new window" works,and left-click doesnt :(

Does anybody have an idea how should I change it?

Thanks in advance...

:)

SOLVED!Like this:

Ok,I ma going to show you what I did,so that this post might actually help someone else :)

My HTML nav code was this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img850/4371/40g8.png

So I listened to the nice man above me :)

And did this with the github source:

add the imageshack url in front of this I can not post 2 links as a new user :/a/img850/6605/uxs5.png

Found this on the github and my regular jquery.nav.js with this right here :https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav,

and added some JS code at the bottom of my page :

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#nav').onePageNav({
                filter: ':not(.external)',
            });
        });

And that was it :) All works now,and I hope this is detailed enough to help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the jquery.nav plugin. which expects only links linking to anchors on the page. try adding the class 'external' to the specific items and it should open the link as expected.

Comment: Thank's for the reply,you're very sweet :)Did you mean something like this:<li class="external-link">
                  <a href="http://www.milan-kresojevic.com"{.section newWindow} target="_blank"{.end}>Blog</a>
                </li>  ?

Comment: as mentioned in the plugin docu, you need a `<a href="/blog" class="external">Blog</a>`